# Popular open source projects using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to find any open source project based on Zend Framework. Something well written and as popular as WordPress or Drupal to see actual benefits of ZF as well as possibly use it as an example.

The only 'showcase' I managed to find is http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14134. But this list looks confusing as for the 'official' PHP framework. The same is about ZF statistics by numbers (http://framework.zend.com/about/numbers) - 10 million downloads against 400 actual projects which is less than 500 examples in the user guide. Also Yahoo chose Symfony for their bookmarks service not ZF.

Am I missing something? Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Magento, an e-commerce platform, was built with Zend Framework.

Comment: I was told the same. But probably 'was' is the main keyword here. I did download the latest version of Magneto 2 days ago - Zend_Cache is the only library used there. Is your information different? Otherwise it looks like they moved away from ZF...

Comment: Months ago, when ZF was under the 1.0 version, there was a link to Magento on the home page. You are probably right Alexander.

Comment: Ok... Zend_Cache is not the only library there. Magento is really built on top ZF. So it may be example #1.

Answer (score 7):

What I have personally found is that the Zend Framework is primarily being used to build internal websites, much like CakePHP and Symfony. They are the open source project, and they are then being used to build great apps.

Not everyone wants to let people know what backend they are using, or what they are using it for. Zend Framework, and other frameworks stay in the background and help the developer of the website build a great application.

Answer (score 6):

[TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/) an open source CMS using the Zend Framework and jquery http://www.tomatocms.com/

Answer (score 5):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) - an open-source statistics system. An alternative for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 4):

These guys rewrote their application using ZF: 
[AtMail webclient](http://atmail.com/webmail-client/)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Magento I have found one more open source project - [Digitalus CMS](http://digitaluscms.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Pimcore](http://pimcore.org) is a great looking cms that uses ZF
and ExtJS.

Answer (score 2):

[Precurio](http://www.precurio.com), an open source intranet portal software, also uses the Zend Framework

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any open source projects, but I have found two aps, intentionaly built to showcase Zend Framework - version 1.8 and 1.9 (should work I think)

- [PASTEBIN](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/189-Pastebin-app-and-conference-updates.html) - application showcasing mostly dojo, but has nicemodel structure, by [Mathew - great blog](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/)
- [StoreFront](http://www.ohloh.net/p/zfstorefront) - a e-commerce application

Answer (score 1):

efront LMS
http://www.efrontlearning.net/

Answer (score 1):

A very neat [CMS written in Zend called Centurion](https://github.com/centurion-project/Centurion/). I googled for some well organized Zend projects with tests, so [here it is](https://github.com/centurion-project/Centurion/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of projects using the Zend Framework, though it's dated : http://devzone.zend.com/article/2060.

And the current list of projects using ZF on SourceForge : http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=zend+framework.

Answer (score 0):

conjoon: www.conjoon.org/, 
Tine 2.0: www.tine20.org/, 
Zoolu: code.google.com/p/zoolu/, 
ecartcommerce: code.google.com/p/ecartcommerce/

Answer (score 0):

We also using Zend Framework 2 on our project - [renbo.cz](https://www.renbo.cz). And I have to say that we are pretty happy with this choice. ZF2 is modular, well written and what is most important - really well documented.